# Python Pandas dataframe create a new column which contains the subtraction from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For now, I have something like:

```
date      item_number

2/28/2020 3.1

2/27/2020 3.9

2/26/2020 2.1

2/25/2020 1.9
```

I would like to have something like:

```
date      item_number delta

2/28/2020 3.1            0

2/27/2020 3.9          0.8

2/26/2020 2.1         -1.8

2/25/2020 1.9         -0.2
```

Any ideas on how to do it? I am a beginner for python and hope to have some suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rolling difference in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48518338/rolling-difference-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) with replace missing value to `0`:

```
df['item_number'] = pd.to_numeric(df['item_number'])
df['delta'] = df['item_number'].diff().fillna(0)
print (df)
        date  item_number  delta
0  2/28/2020          3.1    0.0
1  2/27/2020          3.9    0.8
2  2/26/2020          2.1   -1.8
3  2/25/2020          1.9   -0.2
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael. However, it gives me an error of unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'.

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: @kstst - Sure, give me a sec.

Comment: @kstst - Can you use `df['item_number'] = pd.to_numeric(df['item_number'])` before my solution for convert strings to numbers?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shift`, and fill the initial NaN with a 0:

```
df['delta'] = (df['item_number'] - df['item_number'].shift()).fillna(0.)
```