# Calculating 7 day cumulative change

Tags: python, pandas

I am rather new to python and pandas but not programming.
I have tackled this issue before many different ways but looking for the best way to do it in python and pandas. Given this dataframe below I would like to have another column that is the 7 day cumulative change per day. Do I need to iterate through and calculate it or is there an easier, quicker, more efficient way?
For clarification I want to put in a column the difference of value between the reportdate and the reportdate 7 days before.

```
reportdate  value
2020-09-24  54489
2020-09-25  54516
2020-09-26  55023
2020-09-27  55467
2020-09-28  55513
2020-09-29  55536
2020-09-30  55542
2020-10-01  55569
2020-10-02  55582
2020-10-03  55700
2020-10-04  55714
2020-10-05  55720
2020-10-06  55729
2020-10-07  55756
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! What have you tried so far? Your description is not entirely clear, but it seems like you either want pandas `shift()` or `rolling()` built-in methods. Please [edit] to show a complete [mcve] including expected output and code for your efforts, and we'll be able to help you better

Comment: I am not sure how to make it any clearer... Given this data I want the difference each day befween value for the date 7 days before? I have looked at rolling and shift and I am not sure how it would give me the difference between the days values only the sum or mean type things.

Comment: So for 10/7 it would be the difference between  2020-10-01  55756 and 55569 the value for 10/1 .

Comment: That's where a sample of your expected output based on the given input would be helpful. You could be asking for `df['new_val']=df['value']-df['value.shift(-7)` or `df['value'].rolling(7).diff()` for example

Comment: rolling does not have diff does it?

Comment: My apologies, you're correct. But [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48518338/rolling-difference-in-pandas) has solutions for using rolling with a difference